# Jquery offset method

Tags: jquery

Will the offset method set the element position other than static first,since it is setting the co-ordinates of an element which is possible only when element is positioned other than static.How does it work internally?i m beginner to jquery

```
$("p:last").offset({ top: 10, left: 30 });
```

Comment: Why not try it and see what happens?

Comment: @Kolink which method or procedure to try?

Comment: If you want to know how `.offset()` works internally, see https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/offset.js

Comment: Well, you have a line of code there. Have you tried running it on a page and then using the Inspector or Developer Tools to see what happened?

Comment: @Kolink he is asking how it works internally, that is, to explain the code and how it works

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I don't think a "beginner to jQuery" would have a clue about how any of the vanilla JavaScript that makes it up works, unfortunately...

Comment: @Kolink not so beginner sir.Thanku

Comment: @Kolink unfortunately you're probably right. However, I still think this is an interesting question, and not a complicated one. The jQuery source code is very straight forward in this case, in 2.0 probably even more so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a look at the source you will find that it does change `static` elements to `relative`.

```
// Set position first, in-case top/left are set even on static elem
if ( position === "static" ) {
    elem.style.position = "relative";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The function simply edits the style properties of all the matched elements. The property position is set to relative and the properties top and left take the value you assigned to them.

You could probably achieve the same by calling this:

```
$("p:last").css("position", "relative").css("top", 10).css("left", 30);
```

With the method position() you can get(but not set) the coordinates relative to the parent element.

Comment: He is asking _how_ it works, not what it does.

Comment: Isn't that equal in that case?